# Fatal Error :1:1: Premature end of file. when trying to parse and write an SVG file

Tags: java, svg

I'm parsing a SVG file to draw a map.
This file can be called very often by the app, also 10 times in 2 seconds

Sometimes i'm getting this exception, and so the document it's not drawn.

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
2016-05-24 19:21:25.110 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-65]: SAX exception è: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

The function which causes the exception is:

```
public Document getDocument(String filename) {

        String pathToImage = pm.getProp("upload.location");
        String path = pathToImage + filename;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            logger.error("ParseConfiguration error", e1);
        }

        Document document = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(path);
            document = builder.parse(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("File not found:", e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            logger.error("SAX exception: ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IO exception: ", e);
        }

        return document;
    }
```

in particular the exception comes from `document = builder.parse(is);`

Then, maybe the next call to it goes well and so on, but sometimes i'm getting this exception.
After the document creation, i scan the svg file to change some parameter and then i'll save it.

Can it be that i'm accessing the file while it is still in writing mode by the previous call?

Comment: I imagine your last point is what's happening. You should write to a temp file and then move the complete file into the right place.

Comment: I cannot do it in this way because i could write multiple files at the same rime in different way and so the saved one would be only the last one

Comment: I've no idea why that would be a problem. I'm not suggesting a hardcoded temp file name.

Comment: Sorry maybe i did not understood you... How can i write to a temp file if multiple changes occurr? Don't i have the same problem of accessing the same file?

Comment: You'd could always serialise the changes.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be closing your InputStream when you are done with it?

Comment: Sure, i should... And i will use syncronization to access the file